# AWS CodePipeline: source action has insufficient permissions for CodeStar connection

Tags: aws-codepipeline

I'm setting up a CodePipeline, and I created an action to fetch the source from GitHub.

This requires to set up a connection, which I did, and things look fine also on GitHub's side.

However, if I release a change to the pipeline, I see the following error at the source stage:

```
Insufficient permissions
Unable to use Connection: arn:aws:codestar-connections:us-east-1:REDACTED:connection/REDACTED. The provided role does not have sufficient permissions.
```

I added full CodeStar access to the pipeline's service role (which I found in the pipeline settings) and looks like this:

```
arn:aws:iam::REDACTED:role/service-role/AWSCodePipelineServiceRole-us-east-1-REDACTED
```

Does anybody have any idea of what might be missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The solution was to add this bit to the policy of the service role:

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "codestar-connections:UseConnection",
        "Resource": "insert ARN of the CodeStar connection here"
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me.

Comment: I sometimes wonder if it weren't for these answers anyone would be able to use AWS!

Comment: I am using the CDK v2, my pipeline role `PipelineRole-12345` includes a policy that allows it to assume several other roles  (i.e. `*Sourceproject-2B2Z1X5W31VD` ).  If you're still having problems try adding to one of the roles that are assumed.